# running gstreamer app without v4l2 driver

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to implement a gstreamer pipeline for video streaming without using a v4l2 driver in Linux. The thing is that the video frames I have them already in the RAM(the vdma core which is configured by a different OS on a different core takes care of that) . And also I had difficulties debugging some DMA slave errors which appeared always after a dma completion callback.

Therefore I would be happy if I would not have to use v4l2 driver in order to have gstreamer on top.

I have found this plugin from Bosch that fits my case:
     https://github.com/igel-oss/v4l-gst

My question would be if somebody has experience with this approach and if is a feasible one?

Other question would be how to configure the source in the gstreamer pipeline as it is not a device /dev/videoxxx but rather a memory location or even a bmp file.

Thanks, Mihaita

Comment: I am not completely sure, but you can try something on the lines of reusing the `v4l2src` element src code and instead of device `ioctl` like device `open`, `read` , replace these functions to `read` from your RAM. Another way could be to use the `queue` and then read buffers. However, this would require you to have knowledge of each frame start and end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [appsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html) and repeatedly call [gst_app_src_push_buffer ()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html#gst-app-src-push-buffer).  Your application will have all freedom to read the video data from anywhere it likes - memory, files etc. See also the [relevant section of the GStreamer Application Development Manual](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#inserting-data-with-appsrc).

If you want more flexibility, like using the video source in several applications, you should consider [implementing your own custom GStreamer element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/).